# lim inf of integral involving Wiener process

Tags: probability, brownian-motion, limsup-and-liminf, almost-everywhere

I have the following problem which I do not know how to solve - I know there is a set of results by Donsker and Varadhan, but my maths is not good enough to understand them I'm afraid.
Suppose I have a Brownian motion $ W(t), 0<t<\infty$. I'd like to know if there is any formula for the almost sure behaviour of

$$
\liminf_{T\rightarrow\infty}\int_{0}^{T}\frac{1}{(1+[W(t)]^2)^{2}}dt
$$

I would be really grateful for any help.

Comment: Since the integrand is non-negative, we have $$\liminf_{T \to \infty} \int_0^T \dots = \lim_{T \to \infty} \int_0^T \dots = \int_0^{\infty} \dots $$